# VBA does not recognize the correct number of MS Word windows/documents open

Tags: vba, ms-word

Where I am working, we have software that converts an xml file into a word document.  The only issue is that it can only do 1 xml file at a time, producing 1 word document at a time.  I am trying to find a way to join all the word documents into 1.  Here is the code I came up with.

```
Sub merge()
Dim myDoc As Documents
Dim count As Integer

Set myDoc = Documents
count = myDoc.count

If count <> 1 Then
   For i = 1 To count - 1
      myDoc(i).Select
      Selection.WholeStory
      Selection.Copy
      myDoc(count).Range.Select
      Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
      Selection.TypeParagraph
      Selection.Paste
   Next i
Else
    MsgBox ("No other documents open")
End If

End Sub
```

The only issue I am running into is that when the software converts the xml file into a word document, the VBA does not recognize any of the converted documents even though it is open in MS Word.  If I run code like "application.windows.count or documents.count" it will not recognize it.  If I open any other document the code will merge everything together.  But the converted documents from the software cannot be merged.  Is there anything I can do to force MS Word to recognize the converted documents?

Comment: It's going to depend on how this tools generates the documents. I get the impression that it's creating a *new instance* of the Word.Application each time it runs. If that's the case, then the individual Word instances can't "see" each other. This is something you won't experience working as a user since the installation default is to open anything the user double-clicks on in a currently running instance. What happens to these documents after the tool has created them? Are they saved somewhere?

Comment: Are they open in a different instance of MS Word? You could check via task manager... Can you see the other documents in the VBA IDE Project Explorer?